# When should a trusted user use their delete votes on an answer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

I recently hit 20k rep and gain the privilege to delete answers with negative score.

When should I use my delete votes on answers, given that non-answers can be flagged and resolved with single binding vote by community moderators?

Comment: I intend this to be a FAQ proposal, since I can't find any entry in the FAQs regarding this. Please answer this question with that in mind. Thanks you.

Comment: It could be part of the [privilege explanation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: @nhahtdh: This belongs in the privilege wiki

Answer (score 3):

In these three cases:

- The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
- The answer doesn't answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether
- The answer is not much more than a link.

<s>This can be edited into the [privilege wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user).</s>

I have [added it to the privilege wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66738/17); it ought to sync up with the rest of the sites in a few days.

Comment: I think you have to somehow make it different from the flagging guide. What you mentioned here at first glance would look like targets for flagging, which IMO is much more efficient than casting a delete vote yourself.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Umm, 10k/20k users are the ones who are supposed to act on those flags in the end. The places where you vote to delete are the _exact_ same places where you would flag. Flags are for when you don't have the power to do something for yourself.

Comment: Also, delete votes are tracked in `/tools`, so it's close to being a flag.

Comment: I don't check the delete votes in the tools, since it doesn't show all the pending delete votes (I think the tool as it is is rather useless). 10k/20k users can pile on the flags, but I'd rather let the moderator handle the actual deletion, since I wouldn't want to waste my vote when the moderators can cast a binding vote.

Comment: @nhahtdh: The _whole point_ of the tiered privilege system is so that mods don't have to be the endpoints of all flags. Mods are there to handle any spillover and exceptional cases. If they handled _all_ the flags we'd need a mod team five times as large.

Comment: I think we need stat on how many 20k actually cast delete vote instead of flagging.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yeah, but that's orthogonal to this. The way the system is supposed to work is that the lower reps do all the flagging, and the 10/20ks handle them.

Comment: I believe 10k don't cast delete vote from the tools (and they only pile up flags in the tools when the post actually needs to be deleted). And it need 3 (?) 20k users to cast delete vote, which is hardly scalable with the number of votes given per day.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Again, _it is a separate problem if the users are not using the system the way they are supposed to_. It's perfectly OK if you flag and cast a delete vote as well. However, when you're flagging from tools, _there is not much of a point re-flagging a flagged message_. The mods get it anyway, it just reorders it in the queue. And it's OK if it's not scalable, at least there will be much less flags for the mods to handle.

Comment: Personally, I would rather use flags for posts that moderator can handle, and throw my delete votes on clearly incorrect answers that owner doesn't delete (which moderators will usually leave alone).